# Smoothly snap a rotatable object to degree

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, trigonometry

I have been hacking on this problem for a while and can't seem to find a solution (I am not friends with trigonometry).
I am trying to build an element that the user can "grab" and then rotate. I have it working except for one last feature I can't seem to figure out:
http://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/WbLLzZ?editors=001

(it's long, but I am only asking about how the snapTo() function should work).

What I want is for the object snap to degrees based on the `increments` value. This means that if `snap==true`, the code should calculate the closest estimated `target`s to the point of release of the mouse and based on the direction of rotation smoothly rotate the object to that `target` rotation:
[image]
Since the object is 'grabbed', I calculate the offset at mousedown to object's current rotation, thats where it comes from, so it doesn't just snap to mouse.

So in this case the user rotates the object clockwise and releases the mouse when the objects rotation is between 90° and 45°. Since the direction (identified by the sign of `angle` variable) was positive, the target will be after the Current rotation.

The task is to calculate that target and then smoothly rotate the object to it.

The function I have written for it is based on by autoSpin() function (executes when `spin==false`), which takes a flipped time exponent multiplier `delta` (calculated from the time elapse since mouse was released). `delta` will decrease along a flipped exponent as time passes and so the angle slows down.

There is spinTo() function, please don't judge me I have a feeling it is very stupid:

```
function snapTo() {      
    var elapsed, delta;    
    increments = (typeof increments === 'number') ? Math.floor(increments) : 4;    
    var ia = 360 / increments; //increment angle - snapping points should occur "every ia degrees"
    if (Math.abs(angle % ia) > 0) { //if user turned for more than 1 increment
      var a = lastRot % ia; //check the distance from 
      if (angle > 0){ //positive direction
        amplitude = 50; //if snapping is on, force amplitude
        target = (lastRot - a) + ia;
      }
      if (angle < 0){ //negative direction        
        amplitude = -50;
        target = lastRot - a;
      } 
    } else { //cancel the rotation
      target = rotation;
    }    
    elapsed = Date.now() - timestamp; //time passed since mouse was released
    delta = -amplitude * Math.exp(-elapsed / timeConstant); //the greater the time from mouse release, the smaller this value
    if (delta > 0.5 || delta < -0.5) { //while delta is decreasing...         
      rotate(target - delta - offset); 
      snapFrame = requestAnimationFrame(snapTo); //keep rotation
    } else {                
      rotate(target - offset); //when enough time passes (based on timeConstant), make one final rotation and stop
    }     
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*le sigh
Ok well I had to figure it out on my own. If anyone wants to do this kind of thing, here is one way of doing it:

```
function snapTo() {      
    var elapsed, ease, diff;    
    increments = (typeof increments === 'number') ? Math.floor(increments) : 4;    
    var ia = 360 / increments; //increment angle - this is how large each increment will be
    var a = last % ia; //check the distance from point of mouse release to the previous increment    
    if (movement>0) {
      elapsed = Date.now() - timestamp; //time passed since mouse was released
      ease = 1 - Math.exp((-3*elapsed)/timeConstant); //your easing function formula goes here
      if(a > ia/2) { //if halfway through the increment...
        target = (last - a) + ia; //target next increment
      } 
      else { //else revert to previous increment to the point of mouse release
        target = last - a;
      } 
      diff = target - last; //difference between target and rotation at time of mouse release
      if(ease < 0.95){ //this depends on your easing formula
        rotate(last+diff * ease);
        requestAnimationFrame(snapTo); //don't forget to RAF
      } else { //and for your final frame...
        rotate(last+diff); //make it snappy :P
      }
      console.log(last); //traces of debugging were found in this derelict question...
    }
  }
```

So in here

- `elapsed` is the time passed since the mouse was released
- `increments` is the argument provided by user: how many snapping points will be there
- `ia` is the computed increment in degrees: 360/`increments`
- `last` is the angle recorded on `mouseup` event - "Current rotation" in the diagram. It includes the offset (in my code, its just a "snapshot" of `rotation` at point of release, that is then also reversed in sign because in DOM the coordinate system is y-flipped and I don't like working with that).
- `a` is how much bigger the `last` is than the previous nearest increment point.
- `diff` is the "target" on the diagram - difference between final rotation and `last`
- `ease` is just the value that changes according to your easing function, based on which you either continue calling RAF or finish the animation.
- `timeConstant` is time in milliseconds for how long the animation will take. You can have this or not, depends on your easing formula

A good resource to read in general: [Understanding Easing Functions](http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing)

Also [Desmos graphing calculator](http://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/WbLLzZ?editors=001) is quite good for developing easing formulas.

Oh and: in case anyone is wondering, it doesn't seem possible to pass any kind of non-time-related arguments to RAF callback functions. Seems to break it if I do. So the only solution is to define the `increments` value elsewhere in the code.

[Codepen of the working function](http://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/WbLLzZ?editors=001)

Anyone got a better solution, I am all eyes.